# Nginx revere proxy path not working for node express app

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean, pm2

I have a React frontend app and Node Express Rest API app to be deployed on linux server using nginx and pm2.
React frontend app is deployed by placing the build folder under `/var/www/example.com/html`

For Node express Rest API, I haved used to run it as a process on port `3000`.

In /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, this is how my configuration looks like

```html
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/mirage.video/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        # Without this line routing in your Single Page APP will not work  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /api {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

However when I visit `ip/api`, it shows `Cannot GET /api`

My `server.ts` includes following code

```
app.use(express.json()); // new way to do it

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // new way to do it

app.get("/", (_req, res) => {
  res.send("API Running");
});
```

Is there anything I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are using NGINX as both a web server and as a reverse proxy, with requests with the /api route being proxied to Node Express.  If the Node server doesn't have an api route itself, you generally need to add a rewrite statement to the proxy block, something like:  rewrite /api(.*) $1 break;

This might help:  https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite

Comment: @SScotti , thank you. this works. Can I know how the rewrite statement works ?

Comment: There is plenty of stuff on the internet about that:  https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules .  It isn't necessarily a simple topic.  You can use REGEX for matching, etc. as well.  The NGINX website is a good place to start, but there are many other references out there.